# Qgis web client search

Tags: qgis, geoserver, geoext, qgis-web-client

I install Qgis web client on windows 7 and it's working fine!
Now I wont to setup search feature!

1. First I added line in Apache config file:
   -LoadModule wsgi_module
   modules/mod_wsgi.so
2. In GlobalOption.js I set
   var useGeoNamesSearchBox = false;
   var searchBoxQueryURL
   ="http://localhost:89/qgis-web-client-master/wsgi/search.wsgi?query=";
   var searchBoxGetGeomURL
   ="http://localhost:89/qgis-web-client-master/wsgi/getSearchGeom.wsgi";

When i try to search, i do not get anything!
Is there any example for searching setup?

Comment: First, you have to add the correct mod_wsgi.so too the apache/modules folder.